# css alignment of images

Tags: css, alignment

Seems I cant find correct class to horizontally align the Agent imageswith text below .  site: http://hendersonrealestatepros.com/listings/2724-mintlaw-ave/

tried

```
.connected-agents{
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
width: 70%;
padding: 10px;
}

.connected-agents{
float: left;
width: 70%;
padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Your issues boil down to a number of things. **1**. Specificity conflicts (see **2**). **2**. Multiple widths being set on target element and ancestor elements preventing the alignment you want. **3**. `.connected-agents` is used to wrap other `.connected-agent` elements (mistake?).

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
#listing-agent .connected-agents { 
  display: table-row; 
  } 
  .agent-thumb, .agent-details { 
  display: table-cell; 
  vertical-align: middle; 
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, as you can see it only aligned text left.  correct align horizontally agent image with text below each  http://hendersonrealestatepros.com/listings/2724-mintlaw-ave/

Comment: Add these - 

#listing-agent .connected-agents {
    display: table-row;
}
.agent-thumb, .agent-details {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

Comment: After trying that it likes to only move text to right of images?

Comment: Yes, what more you want to achieve? You want to display all block of people horizontally?

Comment: Align Agent Images Horizontally with Text Block below each agent

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend using `margin: 0 auto;` and `float: none` for #listing-agent so that it will align to the center. please let me know what output you are expecting

Comment: yes, the code i just suggested will align it horizontally

Comment: Hi, I did try your suggestions, but with no changed results

Comment: did you remove this code?  `margin-right: 3.8%; ` because when you say `margin: 0 auto`, it means `margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;` if you don't remove the above code, the block won't align.

Comment: sorry fount it and commented out with no change Odd?

Comment: can you upload the current version? or create fiddle?

Comment: @Lucian your solution does not horizontally align agents. It simply centers the agents.

Comment: upload current version?

Comment: @Greg i have few screenshots prepared for you. that should work.  http://prntscr.com/beq99e  http://prntscr.com/beq9qx  http://prntscr.com/beqa15  http://prntscr.com/beqaa3  this should work

Comment: Here is what i added but little change #listing-agent,
    #contact-form {
  width: 100%;
}
    
.agent-thumb{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
#listing-agent img{
    float: none;
    display: block;
    }
    
.agent-details{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }

Comment: what exactly do you want it to be placed? can you show me in picture? it would be easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a large amount of CSS classes interacting which makes a simple solution a bit tough due to the *"style soup"* (styles overriding styles overriding styles) and markup that could be improved upon.

The one main assumption I'm going to make is that you want the agents to take up the full width that the paragraphs above the agents take up.

1. Remove `float: left;` and `width: 48%;` (possibly the padding too) from `#listing-agent`. You have two selectors setting `float` and `width` for `#listing-agent`. They are `#listing-agent, #contact-form {...}` (in the `<head>` of the page) and `#listing-agent, #listing-agent + #listing-contact {...}` (in impress-agents.css line 141). I would remove `#listing-agent` from those selectors so they are: `#contact-form {...}` and `#listing-agent + #listing-contact {...}`.
2. Remove the child `<div class="connected-agents">` of `#listing-agent`.

Doing those two things will get the agent section the same width as the paragraphs above.

Now to horizontally align the agents (with text below image).

1. Make sure to undo the display table stuff that you added from another answer.
2. Float the agent container element to the left. You have a myriad number of CSS classes to hook onto, `connected-agents vcard post-11274 employee type-employee status-publish has-post-thumbnail hentry offices-tr-realty job-types-broker-salesperson entry`. Use which ever on works best for you. If you choose to use `.connected-agents` make sure to remove the `<div>` mentioned above. Below is one option:

```css
#listing-agent .employee {
    float: left;
    width: auto; /* removes `width: 100%;` set by .hentry and .entry */
}
```

Comment: Great news. one last issue  when i try and center it goes vertical again. any ideas

Comment: What are you trying to center?

Comment: Equally spread them out across. three Agent Images with text below on this page  http://hendersonrealestatepros.com/listings/2724-mintlaw-ave/

Comment: How would you go about it? What are your first thoughts?

Comment: .connected-agents{
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

Comment: I also tried #listing-agent  .employee{
    margin: 0 auto;

Comment: I think you need to brush up on the basics of CSS and HTML elements. Doing so will help solve a number of your issues and improve your code. I'm guessing you're not a developer. `v-align` isn't a valid CSS property. `margin: 0 auto;` only works on block level elements that have a width set. It's hard to know how you want the elements to be _"centered"_. Do the left and right agents have to touch the left/right edges of their container element? Or can they simply be centered from the middle out of their container element? There's a lot of unknowns to provide a proper answer.

Comment: correct, i am learning on my own. What iI am trying to do is have them spaced with same margin left and right of container with inside margins match. search yielded minimal results.